# Alternative to Chrome's Background Fetch Api?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

So I just came across Chrome's ["Background Fetch API"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Background_Fetch_API) and I'm wondering if Firefox and Safari provide a similar API.

Is there an API provided by Firefox and/or Safari that allows applications to successfully fetch large files (e.g. 100mb) - even when users navigate away from the relevant tab or window?

If not, is there a feasible way to polyfill this behaviour?